# Spring Boot @Async - Proxy ERROR

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, асинхронность

И так, у меня есть:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("WebService-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return (throwable, method, objects) -> log.error("Unexpected asynchronous exception at : "
                + method.getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." + method.getName(), throwable);
    }
}
```

Конфиг WebSocket'a

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    private SocketHandler socketHandler;

    public WebSocketConfig(SocketHandler socketHandler) {
        this.socketHandler = socketHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(socketHandler, "/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

Объект SocketHandler'a с асинхронным методом.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Async
    public void handleTextMessage(String text) {
        for (WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) {
            try {
                webSocketSession.sendMessage(new TextMessage(text));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.warn("{}", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        //the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
        sessions.add(session);
    }
}
```

и Сервис, который этим пользуется:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class MyService {

    private SocketHandler socketHandler;

    public TestItemHolder(SocketHandler socketHandler) {
        this.socketHandler = socketHandler;
    }
}
```

периодически при старте приложения я получаю ошибку:

```
2019-11-14 13:35:51.139  WARN 50958 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myService' defined in URL [jar:file:/.../MyService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'socketHandler' is expected to be of type 'ru....SocketHandler' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118'
2019-11-14 13:35:51.182 ERROR 50958 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'socketHandler' could not be injected as a 'ru.....SocketHandler' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:


Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.
```

Собираю проект я Мавеном. Достаточно сделать mave clean... maven package... и полученный проект стартует. Потом опять, пересоберешь - НЕ стартуает, еще раз пересоберешь - Стартует...

Куда посмотреть?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка говорит о том, что тебе надо явно указать создание **proxy**-классов через **CgLib** при помощи `proxyTargetClass = true`. Однако у тебя это уже есть:

```java
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer{
//--
}
```

Но у тебя `@EnableAsync` также присутствует на

```java
@EnableAsync
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {
```

Вероятно они друг друга перекрывают периодически. Этим объясняется то, что проект стартует через раз.

Попробуй убрать `@EnableAsync` с `AsyncConfiguration`

Можно пойти другим путем. Spring пытается создать Proxy-класс над `SocketHandler` через **CgLib**, а не через [JavaProxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html), потому как метод `SocketHandler#handleTextMessage` не наследуется от какого-либо интерфейса. Ты можешь добавить интерфейс, к примеру:

```java
public interface SocketHandlerApi {
    void handleTextMessage(String text);
}
```

И после модифицировать `SocketHandler` примерно так:

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler implements SocketHandlerApi {

    List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Async
    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(String text) {
        for (WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) {
            try {
                webSocketSession.sendMessage(new TextMessage(text));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.warn("{}", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        //the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
        sessions.add(session);
    }
}
```

Тогда ошибка должна также поправиться.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что аннотацию @EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true) нужно включать у всех классов, которые имеют асинхронные методы?

Comment: @VitalyM. Немного дополнил ответ. Не совсем так. Тут надо сначала вообще разъяснить механизмы, через которые работают аннотации `@Async`, `@Transaction` и т.д. Но это тема отдельного вопроса.

Comment: `EnableAsync`  включать нужно один раз. Размещать всё равно где, но лучше у приложения, чтобы все такие аннотации были в одном месте

Comment: Вариант с интерфейсом не как будто тоже не всегда работает. У мен ошибка отвалилась для класса, который реализовывал интерфейсы. Проявилась она почему-то после того, как я один из его интерфейсов отнаследовал от третьего...